# how to use automapper instance api in extension method

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a complex domain object structure:

```
public class CustomerDomainObj
{
public CUSTOMER customer {get;set;}
public ORDER order {get;set;}
public PRODUCT product {get;set;}
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
public string cust_name {get;set;}
public string price {get;set;}
public string description {get;set;}
}
```

I need to map properties of `CUSTOMER`,`PRODUCT` and `ORDER` objects to `CustomerDTO`

For that I have created an extension method:

```
public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(this TDestination destination, TSource source, IMapper mapper)
{
     return mapper.Map(source, destination);
}
```

Configuration:

```
m.CreateMap<CUSTOMER, CustomerDTO>().ForMember(/*Some Code*/);
m.CreateMap<PRODUCT, CustomerDTO>().ForMember(/*Some Code*/);
m.CreateMap<ORDER, CustomerDTO>().ForMember(/*Some Code*/);
```

Usage:

```
var response = _mapper.Map<CustomerDTO>(repoCust.custObj)
                .Map(repoCust.prodObj, _mapper);
                .Map(repoCust.orderObj, _mapper);
```

Everything works fine!

**Question:**

- I am looking for a way to skip passing the `_mapper` instance every time when I try to do some mapping.

Something like :

```
var response = _mapper.Map<CustomerDTO>(repoCust.custObj)
                    .Map(repoCust.prodObj);
                    .Map(repoCust.orderObj);
```

Comment: I think you have only a few options.  (1) pass it in, like you are.  (2) use a Service Locator pattern to get a mapper.  (3) make a static mapper you can set on the class enclosing the extension methods, and set that mapper when your application launches.

Comment: @Amy: I forgot to mention but static mapper is not an option as I would like to write the unit test using mock. With static mapper, I won't be able to do that. For service locator pattern, you want me to use it in an extension method?

Comment: I think those are your only options, unfortunately.  I've run into this before.  I opted to pass it in.

Comment: @Amy ... if you run into this again, you might find my answer usefull

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for an approach like this...

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace sandcastle1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //we create a mapper instance
            var _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(m =>
            {
                m.CreateMap<A, ADto>().ForMember(x => x.Y, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.X));
                m.CreateMap<B, BDto>().ForMember(x => x.bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.foo));
            }).CreateMapper();

            //some dummy POCOs that we can map
            var a1 = new A { X = 1 };
            var a2 = new A { X = 2 };
            var a3 = new A { X = 3 };

            var b1 = new B { foo = 1 };
            var b2 = new B { foo = 2 };
            var b3 = new B { foo = 3 };

            //mapping objects with fluent syntax:
            // -- we do not repeat the mapper as a written parameter
            // -- we do not specify the destination type but assume that there is exactly one TypeMap for the source type
            var result = _mapper

                .Map(a1)
                .Map(a2)
                .Map(a3)

                .Map(b1)
                .Map(b2)
                .Map(b3);


            //presenting the mapping result
            var cnt = 1;
            foreach (var dto in result)
            {
                var propinfo = dto.GetType().GetProperties().First();
                Console.WriteLine($"Mapped object {cnt++} is of Type {dto.GetType().Name} with {propinfo.Name} = {propinfo.GetValue(dto)}");
            }
        }
    }


    //our dummy classes for the mapping
    public class A
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
    }
    public class ADto
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public int foo { get; set; }
    }
    public class BDto
    {
        public int bar { get; set; }
    }



    public static class ExtensionMethodClass
    {
        //the first extension method ... 
        //takes the IMapper and maps the first object 
        //hands down all possible type mappings or throws an exception when we do not have exactly one mapping for the source type
        public static MyFluentResult Map(this IMapper _mapper, object source)
        {
            //build a dictionary that gives us access to information about existing TypeMaps in the Mapper 
            //(we only want to know from wicht source type to which destination type)
            var maps = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps().GroupBy(x => x.SourceType).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().DestinationType);
            Type stype = source.GetType();
            Type dtype;
            if (!maps.TryGetValue(stype, out dtype))
            {
                throw new Exception($"No suitable single mapping found for {stype.Name}");
            }
            //the magic happens here, we aggregate all necessary information for the following steps in this object
            return new MyFluentResult
            {
                Mapper = _mapper,
                Maps = maps,
                ResultsSoFar = new object[] { _mapper.Map(source, stype, dtype) }
            };
        }
        //this method is called for the second and all subsequent mapping operations
        public static MyFluentResult Map(this MyFluentResult _fluentResult, object source)
        {
            //same as above, but we already have the dictionary...
            Type stype = source.GetType();
            Type dtype;
            if (!_fluentResult.Maps.TryGetValue(stype, out dtype))
            {
                throw new Exception($"No suitable single mapping found for {stype.Name}");
            }
            //again we hand down the result and all other information for the next fluent call
            return new MyFluentResult
            {
                Mapper = _fluentResult.Mapper,
                Maps = _fluentResult.Maps,
                //we can simply concat the results here
                ResultsSoFar = _fluentResult.ResultsSoFar.Concat(new object[] { _fluentResult.Mapper.Map(source, stype, dtype) })
            };
        }
        //omitted implementation for IEnumerable sources... but that would look pretty much the same
    }

    //the class that holds the aggregated data.... the mapper... the possible typemaps ... and the result data...
    //wrapped IEnumerable of the results for convinience
    public class MyFluentResult : IEnumerable<object>
    {
        public IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<object> ResultsSoFar { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Type, Type> Maps { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ResultsSoFar.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ResultsSoFar.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```